# On Load event firing when closing Access and throwing "can't move the focus to the control" error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database where I have code on the On Load event of the main form to set focus to a textbox and load a 'new' record. The code is:

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()

    'Makes it so that when frmDiversion_Review loads, it defaults to a new record
           DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
           Me!FromDate.SetFocus

    End Sub
```

FromDate is an unbound date field used in a search/filter section on the header of the form.

I've split the database, and have an .accde file ready to go, but I've noticed that when I close Access when in the .accde file it gives me the following error:

"The expression On Load you entered as the event property setting produced the following error:

> ****NameOfDatabase**** can't move the focus to the control FromDate."

It does not give an error number.

The code is compiled, and I only get this error using the .accde file. I'm at a loss why the On Load event is even firing when I close Access. Any ideas?

Comment: This may be a sign you need to [De-Compile](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/performance/decompile.asp) your app. Do so in main frontend `.accdb` before re-creating `.accde`. At times this weird message can occur for no reason.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I decompiled, went through and did the debug/compile process again, saved, compacted and repaired, and then made a new .accde file, and I am getting the same error.

Comment: Is there any other code behind that form? Check `Form_Close()`.

Comment: There is quite a bit of code, but nothing on the Form_Close event.  There is code on the Form_Open event that just locks certain controls depending on the access level of the user. the FromDate control is not a part of that section, and the error happens regardless of user's access level.

Comment: I use Load event to set focus to control without issue. However, I use dot instead of bang (!) when referencing controls: `Me.FromDate.SetFocus`. But I've never used accde.

Comment: I've tried both dot and bang. I had it originally as a dot, I changed it to bang just to see if it changed anything per chance.

Comment: I don't know if this would have anything to do with it, but I have a login form that opens when Access is opened. When the user enters their password, it opens the form that is throwing the error. The only code on the login is:

Comment: `code` If IsNull(Me.cboUser) Then
    MsgBox "Select a user", vbCritical
    Me.cboUser.SetFocus
Else
    If Me.txtPassword = Me.cboUser.Column(2) Then
        If Me.cboUser.Column(3) = True Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPasswordChange", , , "[UserID] = " & Me.cboUser
        End If
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDiversion_Review"
        Me.Visible = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Password is incorrect", vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation
        Me.txtPassword = Null
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    End If
End If
End Sub `code`

Answer (score 0):

A few weird scenarios may produce this (such as something relating to other forms being closed when you close out...) having references to this form that cause it to open. Hard to say from here.

But there is an easy out... just add this line at the start of the routine

On Error Resume Next

This is safe provided you know there are no real errors in the routine ever, excepting this annoying one that doesn't actually mean anything. If real errors can occur, you will no longer see them if you add this easy-out.

Personally, I'd prefer to find the cause and address it, not least because it seems other forms are trying to open this form while you're busy closing the app, which is an unsettling thought. But... when all else fails, it's a solution.

Comment: I'm hoping to figure it out as well. It seems like a very minor issue, but your solution will be a good temporary backup plan while I try to get some help troubleshooting it.